# GLUON Mobile Can't find bundle for base name com.gluonapplication.views.primary

Tags: javafx, gluon

First I am new to the use of GLUON mobile. I have developed an application in JAVAFX which I eventually want to port to an android device. At this stage I have just been reading as much as I can an viewing Gluon tutorials. I have followed the steps as per https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_run_the_application using initially the default MultiViewProjectFXML. hence the default POM.

I have no issues running the app via javafx:run.

When I do a mvn -Pandroid client:build I get the below error in which the path can't be found:

```
Fatal error:java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.gluonapplication.views.primary, locale en_US
```

I have no doubt made a finger fault somewhere. I have graalvm-ce-java11-21.0.0 along with Java 11. In one tutorial I noted that when mvn -v was run you see reference to graalvm. I see Java version: 11.0.10, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle.

Please let me know if you require any other details in order to assist. Thanks in advance

## Output

```
[com.gluonapplication.gluonapplication:31983]    classlist:   2,208.75 ms,  0.96 GB
[com.gluonapplication.gluonapplication:31983]        setup:     372.72 ms,  0.96 GB
Fatal error:java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.gluonapplication.views.primary, locale en_US
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2055)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1689)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1593)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1284)
    at com.oracle.svm.util.ModuleSupport.getResourceBundleFallback(ModuleSupport.java:82)
    at com.oracle.svm.util.ModuleSupport.getResourceBundle(ModuleSupport.java:58)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.LocalizationFeature.addBundleToCache(LocalizationFeature.java:267)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.LocalizationFeature.addResourceBundles(LocalizationFeature.java:248)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk11.LocalizationFeatureJDK11OrLater.addResourceBundles(LocalizationFeatureJDK11OrLater.java:54)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.LocalizationFeature.afterRegistration(LocalizationFeature.java:155)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$setupNativeImage$11(NativeImageGenerator.java:849)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:70)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:849)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:561)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:476)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Make sure you have the latest Gluon plugin for your IDE. Looks like the pom contains references to resource bundle files that are not in the project, so simply remove the `<bundlesList>` block.

Comment: Thanks. I can now get to install but have hit another issueAEST 2021][INFO] [SUB]  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[Sat. Jan. 30 17:55:02 AEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/AndroidRuntime(30278): Process: com.neoplexus.neochatapp, PID: 30278
[Sat. Jan. 30 17:55:02 AEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/AndroidRuntime(30278): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "getgrgid_r" referenced by "/data/app/com.neoplexus.neochatapp-1/lib/arm64/libsubstrate.so"...
[Sat. Jan. 30 17:55:02 AEST 2021][INFO] [SUB] E/AndroidRuntime(30278):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372

Comment: What is your Android device and Android version?

Comment: Android 6.0.1 oppo A57 device